# Math Calculation for ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional Values

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm using Swift 3.0. 
I've got the following code:

```
var double1 : Double! = 1.0
var double2 : Double! = 2.0
var double3 : Double! = 3.0
```

When I tried to do the calculation like this:

```
let result = double1-double2-double3
```

The compiler gave me the error:
**binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Double!'**

I've found out that *double1-double2* will result a Double value, thus cannot do math with Double!

Then, I've tried:

```
let result = double1! - double2! - double3!
```

The compiler gave me this error:
**ambiguous reference to member '-'**

So what's the correct grammar for this?

Comment: I believe this is actually a bug but I cannot find the duplicate right now.

Comment: What is the practical benefit to use optionals in this case? You should not use implicit unwrapped optionals at all in declaration lines where a default value is assigned. Nevertheless in terms of arithmetics there is no `nil` state anyway.

Comment: [Bug report (SR-1122)](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1122) (resolved, should no longer be an issue in Swift 3.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these custom operator overloads to your project:

```
public func + <T: FloatingPoint>(lhs: T!, rhs: T!) -> T!
{
    if let lhs = lhs, let rhs = rhs
    {
        return lhs + rhs
    }

    return nil
}

public func - <T: FloatingPoint>(lhs: T!, rhs: T!) -> T!
{
    if let lhs = lhs, let rhs = rhs
    {
        return lhs - rhs
    }

    return nil
}

public func * <T: FloatingPoint>(lhs: T!, rhs: T!) -> T!
{
    if let lhs = lhs, let rhs = rhs
    {
        return lhs * rhs
    }

    return nil
}

public func / <T: FloatingPoint>(lhs: T!, rhs: T!) -> T!
{
    if let lhs = lhs, let rhs = rhs
    {
        return lhs / rhs
    }

    return nil
}
```

It will allow for what you were attempting:

```
var double1 : Double! = 1.0
var double2 : Double! = 2.0
var double3 : Double! = 3.0

let result = double1 - double2 - double3 // -4
```

And, as a bonus, this will work with any arbitrary `FloatingPoint` type (including `Float` and `Float80`).

Comment: Nice. Maybe also add `lhs: T!, rhs: T` and `lhs: T, rhs: T!`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround is:

```
let result = (double1 - double2) as Double - double3
```

Or just cast your doubles to non-optionals. You know that you cannot really perform operations on `nil` values, right?

Comment: Thank you. I've found another solution: let result = Double(double1) - Double(double2) - Double(double3).  Ok... It turns out it's a bug...

Answer (score 0):

Ok，I've found one solution. I can use:

```
let result = Double(double1) - Double(double2) - Double(double3)
```

But the code looks anti-humanity. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Define your `Double`s as `Double`:

```
var double1 : Double = 1.0
var double2 : Double = 2.0
var double3 : Double = 3.0
```

The type can also be inferred:

```
var double1 = 1.0
var double2 = 2.0
var double3 = 3.0
```

Comment: The example is for simplicity. I'm using ObjectMapper, so i have to declare my class variables using Double!

Comment: @kilik52: My answer solves your subtraction operator problem. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @Vatsal Manot: no, it's not. I have to define my `Double`s as `Double!`. you cannot change that.

Comment: @kilik52 Vatsal Manot is referring to [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41889110/1457385).

Comment: @shallowThought: oh, my mistake. thank you.